# getting "have offline access" permission request when calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I'am trying to make user authorization with my REST service from android device. After first confirmation everything works correctly, but if i want to get new token with **GoogleAuthUtil.getToken** after clearing the old token with **GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken** I get **com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission** exception which leads to 
app consent screen with **"have offline access"** permission. After i grant the permission i get new token in **onActivityResult** or with **GoogleAuthUtil.getToken**, but if I clear the token again I still receive the Exception calling GoogleAuthUtil.getToken

```
String SCOPE = Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
...    
String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s", CLIENT_ID, SCOPE);    
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(AuthorizedActivity.this, email, scope);
...
//send received token to server for confirmation
...
try {
    GoogleAuthUtil.clearToken(AuthorizedActivity.this, token);
} catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

and my serverside:

```
...    
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
$client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET');
$client->setDeveloperKey('');
$client->authenticate('token_from_device');
return json_decode($client->getAccessToken())->access_token; // temporary
...
```

**and it is still happening after one hour after clearing the token.**

So my question is what am I doing wrong and why do i keep getting the  consent screen after clearing used token. Do i need a specific permisson, wrong scope or I am missing something else?